# HTML variable values not appended to PDF or HTML using mPDF library

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, mpdf

I am using `mPDF` to generate PDF. `$data[0]['nTransactionID'],$data[0]['dDateCreated'],$data[0]['fSubscriptionAmount'], etc...` those variables does not appended to HTML.

```
$data = "<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nUserSubscriptionID] => 45
            [nUserID] => 31
            [nSubscriptionID] => 1
            [nTransactionID] => 2250842904
            [fSubscriptionAmount] => 15.98
            [bActive] => 1
            [dDateCreated] => 2016-02-13 10:44:40
        )

)
</pre>";
```

Here is my code to generate `PDF`:

```
<?php
include_once('../mpdf60/mpdf.php');
global $cfg;
$orderid = post_value('value'); // this value comes from ajax request
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE nSubscriptionID = $orderid";
$data =  $cfg->get($sql,'all',array(),ARRAY_A);
$page = 'A4';
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8' , $page , '' , '' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 1;
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Print Invoice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <p style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5mm;">INVOICE</p>
        <br />
        <table class="heading" style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:80mm;">
                    <h1 class="heading">ABC Corp</h1>
                    <h2 class="heading">
                        123 Happy Street<br />
                        CoolCity - Pincode<br />
                        Region , Country<br />

                        Website : www.website.com<br />
                        E-mail : info@website.com<br />
                        Phone : +1 - 123456789
                    </h2>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="2" valign="top" align="right" style="padding:3mm;">
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>Order No : </td><td>'.$data[0]['nTransactionID'].'</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Dated : </td><td>'.$data[0]['dDateCreated'].'</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Currency : </td><td>USD</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Buyer</b> :<br />
                    Client Name<br />
                    Client Address
                    <br />
                    City - Pincode , Country<br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <div id="content">

            <div id="invoice_body">
                <table>
                    <tr style="background:#eee;">
                        <td style="width:8%;"><b>Sl. No.</b></td>
                        <td><b>Product</b></td>
                        <td style="width:15%;"><b>Quantity</b></td>
                        <td style="width:15%;"><b>Rate</b></td>
                        <td style="width:15%;"><b>Total</b></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:8%;">1</td>
                        <td style="text-align:left; padding-left:10px;">Software Development<br />Description : Upgradation of telecrm</td>
                        <td class="mono" style="width:15%;">1</td><td style="width:15%;" class="mono">'.$data[0]['fSubscriptionAmount'].'</td>
                        <td style="width:15%;" class="mono">'.$data[0]['fSubscriptionAmount'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                        <td>Total :</td>
                        <td class="mono">'.$data[0]['fSubscriptionAmount'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="invoice_total">
                Total Amount :
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:left; padding-left:10px;"></td>
                        <td style="width:15%;">USD</td>
                        <td style="width:15%;" class="mono">'.$data[0]['fSubscriptionAmount'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br />
            <hr />
            <br />

            <table style="width:100%; height:35mm;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:65%;" valign="top">
                        Payment Information :<br />
                        Please make cheque payments payable to : <br />
                        <b>ABC Corp</b>
                        <br /><br />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="box">
                            E &amp; O.E.<br />
                            For ABC Corp<br /><br /><br /><br />
                            Authorised Signatory
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <br />

    </div>
    <sethtmlpagefooter name="footer" value="on" />

</body>
</html>';

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html); 
$mpdf->Output(); 
?>
```

**$orderid = post_value('value'); // this value comes from ajax request**

Comment: show us contents of `$data`. do a `var_dump($data);`

Comment: @B-and-P see updated question

Comment: As @B-and-P said, does your query return something ?

Comment: @Pathik Vejani: are you getting any errors?

Comment: @smdsgn yes i posted what comes in `$data`

Comment: @B-and-P there is no error, i can see in console that in html view there values are printed.

Comment: Your data is a preformatted string as it appears in your post, not a n array

Comment: i have just printed array() which comes in `$data` variable. @B-and-P

Comment: @B-and-P any solution why it is not printing variable values?

Comment: @smdsgn any solution why it is not printing variable values?

Comment: @PathikVejani What do you mean by " i can see in console that in html view there values are printed". Title of your post states that values not showing in PDF and HTML

Comment: I get the data in `$data` variable using query and then generate the `PDF` @B-and-P

Comment: @B-and-P i am trying to generate `PDF` from ajax request taht is why i wrote that data is coming in ajax  request, but cannot append query data to HTML